# Is there a difference between `Series.replace()` and `Series.map()` in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

Both `pandas.Series.map` and `pandas.Series.replace` seem to give the same result. Is there a reason for using one over the other? For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series(['Yes', 'No'])
df

0    Yes
1     No
dtype: object
```

```
df.replace(to_replace=['Yes', 'No'], value=[True, False])

0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

```
df.map({'Yes':True, 'No':False})

0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

```
df.replace(to_replace=['Yes', 'No'], value=[True, False]).equals(df.map({'Yes':True, 'No':False}))

True
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Both of these methods are used for substituting values.

From [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) docs:

> Replace values given in to_replace with value.

From [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) docs:

> Used for substituting each value in a Series with another value, that may be derived from a function, a dict or a Series.

They differ in the following:

1. `replace` accepts str, regex, list, dict, Series, int, float, or None.
   `map` accepts a dict or a Series.
2. They differ in handling null values.
3. `replace` uses `re.sub` under the hood.The rules for substitution for re.sub are the same.

Take below example:

```
In [124]: s = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])    
In [125]: s
Out[125]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64

In [126]: s.replace({0: 5})
Out[126]: 
0    5
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64

In [129]: s.map({0: 'kitten', 1: 'puppy'}) 
Out[129]: 
0    kitten
1     puppy
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
dtype: object
```

> As you can see for `s.map` method, values that are not found in the dict are converted to NaN, unless the dict has a default value (e.g. defaultdict)

> For `s.replace`, it just replaces the value to be replaced keeping the rest as it is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those details that distinguish the two methods.